# How can I retrieve a value from HashMap with a String when the Key is a custom class object?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have a `HashMap<CustomClass1, ArrayList<CustomClass2>>` called map.

Is it possible to get the `ArrayList<CustomClass2>` using a String contained within CustomClass1? e.g. I would like to say `map.get("zone1")` and get the matching ArrayList. This is for a school project and I have to use the HashMap described above. This resembles my code:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      HashMap<CustomClass1, ArrayList<CustomClass2>> map = new HashMap<CustomClass1, ArrayList<CustomClass2>();

      CustomClass1 example = new CustomClass1("zone1");

      map.put(example, new ArrayList<CustomClass2>());

      //Later in the code where I don't have the objects in scope (except for map)...
      ArrayList<CustomClass2> value = map.get("zone1");

   }

   class CustomClass1 {
      private final String name;
      //Additional variables

      public CustomClass1 (String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
         return name.hashCode();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         ...
         String test = (String) obj;
         if(test.equals(this.name))
            return true;
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

So far I have tried overriding the hashCode() and equals() methods in my CustomClass1 so that it uses the String's hashCode. From my understanding, when I call the map.get(obj) method, it calls obj.hashCode() to find the correct bucket and then obj.equals() to see if it is the correct object. I think I am wrong in thinking this, since I keep getting null values as a result and the equals() method in CustomClass1 is never called.

See comments for workaround/solution.

Comment: Is your `CustomClass1` really so simple? If so, just create a new one every time you want to query the map, `map.get(new CustomClass1("zone1"));`. Otherwise, why is `CustomClass1` the map's key type?

Comment: Your equals implementation is wrong. It violates the contract of equals. equals must be commutative: a equals b iff b equals a. And a String will never be equal to a CustomClass1. Fix the equals method (let your IDE generate it for you). For the rest, read Sotirios's comment.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, the CustomClass1 contains about 5 other variables. CustomClass1 is the map's key because it is an explicit requirement in my school project.

Comment: @JBNizet I see! Maybe I'll have to look into other ways to retrieve the value. Would you have any ideas that come to mind?

Comment: If the key contains 5 other values, then clearly, thr string is not sufficient to uniquely identify one of the keys in the map. So there might be several keys in the map for a given string. All you can do is iterate through the enties of the map and find all the ones whose key has the given string.

Comment: I ended up taking the advice of @JBNizet . Scraped the hashCode() and equals() overrides, but instead created another `HashMap<String, CustomClass1>` to help reference each object by the string (which is unique per my professor's instructions).